# Are the big O complexities correct in my programs

Tags: java, big-o

I'm learning all about big O and I trying to get the Big Complexity of each of my programs. I want to make sure my my big complexities are correct.

Program 1:

Step 1 - Read all words from file `O(n)`, n is the size of the wordlist 
Step 2 - Loop through the characters of each word and manipulate them (I won't go into details what this does, its just a loop)- `O(m)` where m is the number of characters in the word 
Step 3 - Insert into a HashMap `O(1)`

Total - `O(n + m)`

Program 2:
Step 1 - Pass in word to program
Step 2 - Look up word in hashmap - `O(1)`
Step 3 - Loop through the characters of each word and manipulate them `O(m)`, where m is the number of characters in the word
Step 4 - Enter word into a function - I calculated this to be `O(2^m)`, where m is the number of characters in the word
Step 5 - Lookup word again in hashmap `O(1)`

```
O(2^m + m)
```

Program doesn't involved O(n) because I am just looking up the hashmap. The only complexity the looping through the characters of the passed in word

Comment: For step 2 of program 1, you don't seem to be taking into account that you are doing that for each word

Comment: "oop through the characters"? object oriented programming through the characters? ondulating ornithopers processing through the characters?

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through all characters in all words is O(n*m), where n is the number of words and m is the max length of the words

Insertion and lookup for a hashmap is technically O(n) (if all elements hashed to the same value), but if your professor said that it's O(1) then go with that

We can't help you with "Step 4 - enter word into a function" without knowing what the function is

Comment: This is correct - The Big O of step 4 is O(2^m)
Ah, lookup should be worst case. So lookup should be O(n)

Comment: Would this be correct? Program 1 - O(2n * m) = O(n * m)
Program 2 - O(2n + 2^m + m) = O(n + 2^m + m)

Comment: O(n + 2^m + m) would reduce to O(2^m), possibly to O(n * 2^m) if m might be small